# Gluing of static blocks and fields

Tags: java

I just wonder, is this:

```
static{ i = 10; }
static Integer i = 7;
static{ i = 12; }
```

same as this:

```
static Integer i;
static{
    i = 10;
    i = 7;
    i = 12;
}
```

Will it be compiled into the same bytecode?

Comment: Same in what way? It looks rather different to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
static{ i = 10; } 
static Integer i = 7; 
static{ i = 12; }
```

Will define a static variable named `i` and set it's value to <strike>10</strike>, no <strike>7</strike>, no 12. Very bad style as the final variable depends on the order of statements.

```
static{
    Integer i = 10;
    i = 7;
    i = 12;
}
```

On the other hand will create a Variable `i` that lives the whole three lines, has values of 10, 7 and 12 and is afterwards forgotten / not accessible any more. Extremly useless.

```
Integer i;
static{
    i = 10;
    i = 7;
    i = 12;
}
```

However will not compile at all - because `i` cannot be references from static context.

```
static Integer i;
static{
    i = 10;
    i = 7;
    i = 12;
}
```

Would yield same results as first approach. I will not however compare Bytecode here.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Thanks for point me out my misprintings. But I asked about bytecode. However, I appreciate your work and up-voted it, more over I've read you answers to other questions and up-voted them too. Good job, Jan!

Comment: Thanks - you might want to edit your question then to stress out you need the bytecode comparison (and maybe some info why you need that?)

Answer (score 0):

`static` block is just like another block. Any variables inside have the scope of that block. Not even to the sibling `static` blocks.

That means, in the second *way* of the implementation in your question, `Integer i` is local to `static` block, not a static class member, not available outside the block.